# Proving if $f_{\omega}:\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow[ ]{} \mathbb{C}$ as $f_{\omega} (n) := e^{2\pi i \omega n}$ is periodic

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

For $\omega \in \{0,1)$ we define the following function:

$f_{\omega}:\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow[ ]{} \mathbb{C}$ as $f_{\omega} (n) := e^{2\pi i \omega n}$

Can this be proved $f_{\omega} \Leftrightarrow \omega \in \mathbb{Q} $ ?

Thanks.

Comment: If $\omega\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\omega=\frac{a}{b}$ where $(a,b)=1$ are both integers. Then letting $n=b+1$, we get that $f_{\omega}(b+1) = (e^{2\pi i})^a e^{2\pi i \omega} = f_{\omega}(1)$. Therefore $f_\omega$ is periodic mod $b$.

Comment: Really intelligent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}f_\omega\text{ is periodic} &\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\forall n\in\mathbb{Z} :& f_\omega(n) = f_\omega(n + T) \\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\forall n\in\mathbb{Z} :& e^{2\pi i \omega n} = e^{2\pi i \omega (n+ T)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 
&\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\forall n\in\mathbb{Z} :& e^{2\pi i \omega n} = e^{2\pi i \omega n}e^{2\pi i \omega T} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& && 1 = e^{2\pi i \omega T} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}:& 2\pi i k = 2\pi i \omega T \\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}:& k = \omega T \\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\exists T\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}:& &\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}:& \frac{k}{T} = \omega\\
&\Leftrightarrow& &\omega\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{align*}